# Gitlab CI runner is offline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Recently our internal Gitlab upgraded to **10.8.7**, all runner are down as expected. So I tried to upgrade the runner to the latest following the [upgrade](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/install/linux-manually.md#update). Luckily **three** out of five hosts are working in `shell` mode.

But **TWO** of them are not working as expected, I tried:

```
$ sudo gitlab-runner restart
$ sudo gitlab-runner list
$ sudo gitlab-runner verify
$ sudo reboot # the last try when all the above failed
```

It's working as it says:

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=5136 revision=7f00c780 version=11.5.1
Running in system-mode.                            

Verifying runner... is alive                        runner=db05dfa6
```

But **Runner is offline** stands out in the runner management page.

#### Upgrade 2018-12-13

I manually **paused** all the other active runners online (in our group runner management page `<our_internal_host>/groups/<our_group>/-/settings/ci_cd#runners-settings`), it's up then. Weird design, perhaps it's just sleeping or relaxing when jobs are not that heavy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, an upgrade implies (as [discussed here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/runners-paused-even-when-they-are-running/7830)) to reinstall the workers.

> I think I was just running a worker version that was too old and some changes were made that made the older version incompatible.

And the pause function does not seem to be available through the GitLab web UI yet ([issue 44377](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/44377))